# Drag and Drop something

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, draggable

I made a `class Schalter` (eng. switch) and now I want to drag and drop this to an other position. The `Schalter` is a just an object with 0 or 1 as output and it has some drawing in it. I tried something but it just worked half. When I move it it moves much too fast. 
Here the code I tried:

```
namespace Schaltungszeichner {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        s = new Schalter(this);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private bool myMouseDown = false;
    private int myMouseX, myMouseY;

    Schalter s;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        s.zeichnen(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (myMouseDown) {
            s.X += e.X - myMouseX;
            s.Y += e.Y - myMouseY;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        myMouseDown = false;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (s.isClicked(e.X, e.Y)) {
            s.Out = !s.Out;
            myMouseDown = true;
            myMouseX = e.X;
            myMouseY = e.Y;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MouseEventArgs holds the mouse position **relative to the object which owns the event** and not the object being moved. You need to account for this by subtracting the starting position of the moving object.

In *Form1_MouseDown* change:

```
myMouseX = e.X;
myMouseY = e.Y;
```

to:

```
myMouseX = e.X - s.X;
myMouseY = e.Y - s.Y;
```

And in *Form1_MouseMove* change:

```
s.X += e.X - myMouseX;
s.Y += e.Y - myMouseY;
```

to:

```
s.X = e.X - myMouseX;
s.Y = e.Y - myMouseY;
```

I would also consider renaming *myMouseX* and *myMouseY* to something that reflects the values that they now hold, like *differenceX* and *differenceY*.